# Manually set section on newpage

Tags: sectioning

I want to set a section manually on a new page, basically, the package we use is showing each section on the new page and I want only one section on the new page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show us what you try so far (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Do you mean you want to customize the `\section` command to always start on a new page, or do you use a package for that? Is the package public or did you or your colleagues create it? Imho, the question is unclear, I don't know what you want. Please note that you should always (where possible) post a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) that begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`, including all packages and code needed to show your issue, but no packages and that are unrelated.

Comment: You could use `\clearpage` prior to every `\section` as a manual solution.

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage}{}{}` perhaps?

Comment: can you share a page set up for a final year project report in latex. currently, i am using  \documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}